# Why does the exercise level impact the nail growth rate?

Tags: human-biology

I read on https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Nail_(anatomy)&oldid=863800434#Growth:

> Actual growth rate is dependent upon age, sex, season, exercise level, diet, and hereditary factors.

Why does the exercise level impact the nail growth rate?

Comment: Had you looked up the reference that wikipedia cites?

Comment: @BPinto i tried but it's behind paywall.